# Connect to Database through rest assured (REST API automation)

Tags: postgresql, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

We are automating testing of REST APIs using `serenity-rest-assured`. A requirement is to connect to a PostgreSQL database and compare the `GET` API call values with the database table values.

I searched over the internet and couldn't find an answer. I may not be using the right search keywords.

Please guide, can it be done connecting to DB and test the API result?

Comment: Use JAVA to connect to the database and then carry out with your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it out, The below is enough to prove that you can get the values from the database and validate against the values you get as a part of your Rest Assured implementation.

This is a small piece of code which serves the purpose and you can improvise it based on your requirement

Here's my class and I hope the code is self explanatory

```
  public class S_62551943 {

    // Declaration of the variables
    
    private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dvdrental";
    private final String user = "postgres";
    private final String password = "root";
    public static String fname = null;

    // Method to initalize connection to the database and execute query
    
    public void connect() {

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            {
                if (conn != null) {

                    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select first_name from actor where last_name = 'Lollobrigida'");
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    {
                        while (rs.next()) {

                            fname = rs.getString("first_name");
                            System.out.println("The value from the table is : "+fname);
                        }
                    }

                } else
                    System.out.println("Failed to connect");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Main method and Rest Assured Code
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S_62551943 app = new S_62551943();
        app.connect();      
        given().when().get("https://reqres.in/api/users/2").then().body("data.first_name", equalToIgnoringCase(fname));
        System.out.println("Execution Successful");
    }

}
```

More information on Postgres - https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable guidance.